# Why is the intersection distance the same of all objects, even though they have different positions?

Tags: three.js, 3d

We have three spheres

```
const object1 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 16, 16),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#ff0000' })
)
object1.position.x = - 2

const object2 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 16, 16),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#ff0000' })
)

const object3 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 16, 16),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#ff0000' })
)
object3.position.x = 2
```

And a raycaster

```
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

const rayOrigin = new THREE.Vector3(-3, 0, 0);
const rayDirection = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);

raycaster.set(rayOrigin, rayDirection);

const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([object1, object2, object3])
console.log(intersects)
```

Logging the intersects array, we get this:

```
0: {distance: 2.5, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: {…}, …}
1: {distance: 2.5, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: {…}, …}
2: {distance: 2.5, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: {…}, …}
length: 3
```

Why is the distance the same for all spheres? Shouldn't the distances be 0.5, 2.5 and 4.5 respectively? What am I missing?

Comment: did you ever render before calling the raycaster? Try calling `updateMatrixWorld()` on your objects.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. It wasn't my code, it's an example from Three.js Journey.

Comment: @pailhead Could you write your comment as an answer to accept and conclude the question?